# How to implement an ItemsControl3D which can use templates of Visual3D?

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

I'm looking for something like a ContainerUIElement3D which supports the ItemsSource property and an ItemTemplate property which I can use within a Viewport3D. My aim is to be able to write something like:

```
<ItemsControl3D ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl3D.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate3D>                        
            <!-- My template which defines the binding to each item. -->
        <DataTemplate3D>
    </ItemsControl3D.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl3D>
```

I'm looking for tips on how to implement this. The first tricky part is to create a DataTemplate3D which can construct the Visual3D needed to add to the ItemsControl3D.

I've been using .NET reflector to browse through the implementation of ItemsControl and DataTemplate, but I soon realised that I don't have a deep enough understanding and enough time to come up with a solution on my own.

Comment: please some we have some more background on what you are trying to atrive and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an implementation of ItemsControl3D made by DKT @ [Pelebyte](http://pelebyte.net/blog/2009/09/22/more-2d3d-tricks-itemscontrol3d/) blog. I haven't tryed it. But I sure will.

Regards